# Is there a Windows Phone alternative for the Android game MoveIt?

Tags: game, windows-phone

Is there a Windows Phone alternative for the Android game MoveIt?

This game is about moving a specific block from one position (mostly left bottom) to another position (top right) by moving other blocks in the way.